# Loop over directory then run command

Tags: python

Ive spent considerable time trying to essentially loop over a root directory, and then run a command against each directory like:

```
for dirs in os.walk(cbdir):
    print(dirs)
```

this will output like:

```
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/.git/refs', ['heads', 'tags', 'remotes'], [])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/.git/refs/heads', [], ['master'])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/.git/refs/tags', [], [])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/.git/refs/remotes', ['origin'], [])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/.git/refs/remotes/origin', [], ['HEAD'])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/global', ['src'], ['build.gradle', 'settings.gradle'])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/global/src', ['main'], [])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/global/src/main', ['gateway'], [])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/global/src/main/gateway', ['config', 'policy'], [])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/global/src/main/gateway/config', [], ['global-policies.yml'])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/global/src/main/gateway/policy', ['global-policies'], [])
('CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example/global/src/main/gateway/policy/global-policies', [], ['global-received-policy.xml', 'global-completed-policy.xml'])
```

How can i only grab for example `CODE_BASE/gateway-developer-example`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) as such:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cbdir):
    print(root)
```

Usually, I use os.walk as such:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cbdir):
    for filename in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        # do something with path
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `print(dirs[0])`.